# Determine invertibility condition of a vector-to-vector function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, optimization

In this paper [1], the following vector-to-vector function is introduced:

$$f(\mathbf{z}) = \mathbf{z} + \mathbf{u} h(\underbrace{\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{z}}_{\text{dot product}} + b)$$

where $\mathbf{z}, \mathbf{w}, \mathbf{u} \in \mathbb{R}^D$, $b\in\mathbb{R}$, and $h$ is the element-wise tanh function (a strictly increasing function). The paper calls this the *planar flow* transformation, though the name itself is unimportant for the context of this question.

The paper claims that $f$ is invertible as long as $\mathbf{w} ^T \mathbf{u} \geq -1$, but I disagree (see comment at the end).

Here's a summary of their constructive proof for finding $\mathbf{z}$, given that we know $\mathbf{w}, \mathbf{u}, b$ and $\mathbf{y}=f(\mathbf{z})$:

(1) Decompose $\mathbf{z}$ into a component parallel to $\mathbf{w}$, $\mathbf{z}_{||}$, and a component perpendicular to $\mathbf{w}$, $\mathbf{z}_{\perp}$. Then, clearly, we have

$$\mathbf{y} = f(\mathbf{z}) = \mathbf{z}_{\perp} + \mathbf{z}_{||} + \mathbf{u} 
 h(\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{z}_{||} + b).$$

(2) Finding $\mathbf{z}_{\perp}$ (50% of the job done): $$\mathbf{z}_{\perp} = \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{z}_{||} - h(\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{z}_{||} + b).$$

(3) Finding $\mathbf{z}_{||}$ (the remaining 50% of the job):

Here, they used a clever argument. Since $\mathbf{z}_{||}$ is parallel to $\mathbf{w}$, it can be expressed as

$$\mathbf{z}_{||} = \alpha \frac{\mathbf{w}}{||\mathbf{w}||^2}$$

Therefore, if we multiple both sides of

$$f(\mathbf{z}) = \mathbf{z} + \mathbf{u} h(\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{z} + b)$$

by $\mathbf{w}$, we get

\begin{array}
\mathbf{w}^T f(\mathbf{z}) &= \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{z} + \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{u} h(\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{z} + b) \\
&= \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{z}_{||} + \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{u} h(\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{z}_{||} + b) \\
&=\alpha + \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{u} h(\alpha + b).
\end{array}

The paper says that as long as the right-hand side is a non-decreasing function, then the equation above is invertible with respect to $\alpha$, i.e., its derivative $1 + \mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{u} h'(\alpha+b) \geq 0 \rightarrow \mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{u} \geq - \frac{1}{h'(\alpha + b)}$. Finally, since $0 \leq h'(\alpha + b) \leq 1$, we would have $\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{u} \geq -1$.

**Here's my question.** Why can't the right-hand side be a non-increasing function?

[1]: https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.05770)